# How to restore satin/brushed finish on brass

Tags: metal, finishing, refinishing

Trying to restore this piece of plumbing I bought and accidentally scratched.

In the image below you can see one of the original scratches at the bottom.

I did some research online and found that the brushed look can be restored with a scouring pad, like the green side of a sponge. I tried this but it instead appears to be removing more of the finish and making the surface more reflective. In the image below at the top left corner of the piece, you can see a patch which appears less brushed, which is where I scrubbed with the scouring pad.

Any tips on how to restore this piece?

[image: brass restoration]

Comment: You need to match whatever grit they used when creating the brushed finish in the first place. Some experimentation may be in order. Start with 1000 grit paper, and if that's not enough, work your way down to more aggressive grits. Perhaps test on another piece of brass that you might have. You also need to sand it in a single direction.

Comment: @LarryBud - that ought to be an answer, really.

Comment: First off, to restore to original condition, you are not **merely** going to be "re-brushing the brushed finish" you are also going to have to replace the lacquer (typically) on top of that, or you'll have *nice old-fashioned brass that you get to polish every week or it looks terribly tarnished.* Most modern folks don't have time for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @LarryBud, I'll try that out

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about the lacquer @Ecnerwal, I did a quick search and found 'Mohawk Lacquer for Brass Matte'. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Not specifically that particular brand, but generally, almost any brass object in modern commerce is lacquered to prevent tarnish and preserve the surface finish.